# Changing users's passwords on Hashicorp Vault

Tags: authentication, password-protection, policy, hashicorp-vault

I just launch a vault server and created two policies, one for users and another for admin. I created users with a default password but each time I want to modify the password as a user, it doesn't work.
Here is the policy

```
path "example-user-secret/*" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}
path "auth/example-user-secret/users/{{identity.entity.name}}" {
 capabilities = ["update"]
 allowed_parameters = {
     "password" = []
 }
}
```

I was expecting users to be able to login to their account and change their password.